# how to add special characters when adding new products in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to add a new product with a URL with special characters and capital letters.
Example: default URL Magento

domain.com/product-url.html

The thing I want
Example
domain.com/Product,Url(New-Url).html

any solution or module.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you want URL like this. anyway **It is not possible and never suggested as per SEO rule.**

You must know you are trying to break magento and SEO rule